# Error while importing database using mysqldumper

Tags: mysql, database

I had error that was breaking my database restoration, but than I read this.

http://forum.mysqldumper.de/character-set-client-can-t-be-set-to-the-value-of-null-t6088.html

Now, if I do so, I have this errors, can I ignore them?

```
08.03.2014 09:22:49 :   Restore of db `root`
Error-Message : Restore failed: Variable 'character_set_client' can't be set to the value of 'NULL'
SQL : /*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;

08.03.2014 09:29:51 :   Restore of db `root`
Notice : Variable 'character_set_client' can't be set to the value of 'NULL'
SQL : /*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;

08.03.2014 09:29:51 :   Restore of db `root`
Notice : Variable 'collation_connection' can't be set to the value of 'NULL'
SQL : /*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to import database with mysql in command Line ? 
mysql -u user -p database < your file

Regards,